# is it safe to create mysql database by just creating its directory?

Tags: mysql, table, best-practices

**context**: I want a separate encrypted filesystem per database (to have a separate key) on MySQL 5.7 but if I mount it before  I execute `CREATE DATABASE foo` it fails with error `database exists`, and mouting the filesystem after is a bit risky to me.

So I noticed I can "create" a database in MySQL but just creating a folder inside the mysql datadir and creating tables after causes no trouble. I know this is dirty but this way it simplifies the integration with the creation of the filesystem underneath (as it appeared as the folder when lie the tables).

Does creating database this way is safe?

Comment: Database creation consists from 2 steps: 1) create database directory 2) store the info about the database in system tables. If both directory and correct info in system tables exists then the database is accessible without any issue, and it doesn't matter does the directory was created by MySQL server or manually.

Comment: I noticed there is a missing file named "db.opt" containing collation information wrt to the "CREATE DATABASE" method though

Answer (score 0):

UNSAFE!

Use `CREATE DATABASE`.

- `mkdir` probably works for `ENGINE=MyISAM`, but that old engine should not be used anymore.
- InnoDB needs to know what is going on.
- You noticed `db.opt`; but what if something else gets added in the future?
- MySQL 8.0 has an internal "data dictionary" that would be totally confused by that mkdir.
- And who knows what future versions will be like !

It is possible to execute a command on the `mysql` commandline tool.  This makes `CREATE DATABASE` a one-liner, albeit more verbose than a simple `mkdir`.

If you want a table or partition to be on a different physical drive, check out the limited capabilities of specifying the location for the `DATA DIRECTORY`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-table-external.html

Comment: The test I did was with `ENGINE=InnoDB`. The problem is not about verbosity or one-liner, this is the integration with a separate partition (first paragraph of my question), if this is not clear I can add information.

Comment: @BaptisteMille-Mathias - I added a paragraph with a link.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, I already came across it before asking the question, this is interesting but not relevant, as I do not plan to store outside datadir and it's about individual table however I'd like to have the same for database.